# Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB

Tags: centos, snmp

I am using centos Operating System.
i am trying to get the memory statistics of localhost through `snmpget` command, i am getting this error.

```
snmpget -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6
Error in packet
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailReal
```

But, if i fire this one .. i am getting the output..

```
snmpget -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (58756) 0:09:47.56
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong. I exported the path of `/usr/share/snmp/mibs/` to `$PATH` variable.
can any one help me out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd better read the FAQ page of net-snmp,

http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ:Applications_09

You should use

`snmpget -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0`.

Comment: Also useful to do snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.1 and you will see what OIDs exist in your tree

Comment: We were having the same issue, (for a piece of networking equipment though) however our instance sub-identifier was 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

> snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost iso.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6

Use this.