# SNMP OID for getting manufacturer serial number with SNMP version 1

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm unable to get the manufacturer serial number when I do an SNMP get on an OID `.2.47.1.1.1.1.11.1.0`. If I do an `snmpget` with the below command on the OID with the command:

```
snmpget -v1 -c public 192.168.4.99 .2.47.1.1.1.1.11.1.0
```

I get the message:

> Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
>   Failed object: joint-iso-ccitt.47.1.1.1.1.11.1.0

I did search on google for the possible cause of error by going to this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444248/reason-nosuchname-there-is-no-such-variable-name-in-this-mib) as it is caused by missing the instance subidentifier.

I performed an SNMPtranslate for the OID and I got the below string `joint-iso-ccitt.47.1.1.1.1.11.1.0`.

And when I performed an `snmpwalk` on the OID by the below command i get the message as `END OF MIB`.

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c public 192.168.4.1 .2.47.1.1.1.1.11.1.0
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and let me know the exact generic OID to get the manufacturers serial number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who tells you the OID is `.2.47.1.1.1.1.11.1.0`?

Seriously speaking, a normal OID starts with .1, except .0.0 which is very special.

Comment: So what could be a generic oid to get an serial number out of a device , is there a way to find the same. I got this oid from google.

Comment: There is no generic OID to get a serial number out of a device, so if you want to learn such an OID, go to the device vendor and contact its support guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with walking the top of the MIB tree, you'll soon find out which variables your equipment supports:

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c public -Ont 192.168.4.1 .1
```

Remove the "-Ont" to get translated names, where possible, instead of the fully numeric OIDs.

If you're looking for vendor-independent data, you could look into a MIB that most equipment supports, SNMPV2-MIB:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3418.txt

However, you'll find it does not contain any serial number variable. Most vendors provide a vendor-specific (or product-specific) MIB which will define, among other things, serial number. However, like most things in SNMP, it's entirely up to each vendor which MIBs they choose to implement.