# GetRequestMessage doesn't reply correctly while GetNextRequestMessage does with #SNMP

Tags: snmp, sharp-snmp

I've been working with #SNMP library lately. My problem is whenever I send a GET request to an agent it replies with NoSuchObject ,however when I tried GETNEXT or GETBULK request it worked just fine. I literally did the same as examples codes do at github. I wonder why GET request didn't work while GETNEXT did.

Comment: Use a good enough SNMP book to learn what is `NoSuchObject`, and then the answer is clear. That has nothing to do with #SNMP.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444248/reason-nosuchname-there-is-no-such-variable-name-in-this-mib

Comment: the oid you try to get end with .0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the OID you try to GET ends with .0?
GETNEXT does not need to end with .0 but for using GET you must identify the OID as a leaf. I'm guessing you just need to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Those are two completely different SNMP operations.

When you GET an object, the object must exist otherwise you get NoSuchObject.

When you GETNEXT an object, you get the first object that exists *after* the OID you specified.

You should brush up on your SNMP knowledge before attempting to implement a manager.